# Return iterator of a sublist c++

Tags: c++, list, iterator

We have a list

```
std::list<int> list;

// fill part of the list with 5
list.push_back(5);
list.push_back(5);
list.push_back(5);

// fill part of the list with 10
list.push_back(10);
list.push_back(10);
list.push_back(10);

// iterator that starts with 5
std::list<int>::iterator iterFiveBegin = list.begin();


//
std::list<int>::iterator iterEnd = list.end();
```

How can I get the iterator `std::list<int>::iterator iterTenBegin` of the list where it starts with "10"?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Firstly, don't use variable name `list`, try `intList` instead.

You may use `std::find`

```
std::list<int>::iterator it = std::find (intList.begin(), intList.end(), 10);
```

Per  [`std::find` documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find):

> std::find
>   **Return value**
>   Iterator to the first element satisfying the condition or last if no such element is found.

Comment: Thanks. And it gives the first element it finds in the list...The same works with containers, in this case I need to overload '==' operator of the container, right?

Comment: @VyacheslavKorchagin If you mean standard library containers, these already have `==` operators. It just requires that the contained types have `==`.

Comment: @juanchopanza I meant list of classes, and I need to find an element where one of the class's attribute changes. (e.g. classA.var in the std::list<classA*>). In that case I need to overload '==' in the classA, I think

Comment: @VyacheslavKorchagin then you need to overload the `==` operator for customized classes.

Comment: @VyacheslavKorchagin list of pointers is not the same as list of classes. For the former, you will have to use `std::find_if`.

Answer (score 4):

Just use [std::find](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find), from the `<algorithm>` header:

```
std::list<int>::const_iterator ten = std::find(list.begin(), list.end(), 10);
```

Make sure to check that it is valid:

```
if (ten == list.end())
{
  // no 10 found in list
}
```

Also, don't name your `std::list` instance "list".

Answer (score 0):

if your list is sorted, I guess you can use std::lower_bound and std::upper_bound